# Is "during the period of..." acceptable?

Tags: prepositions, time

I am not a native speaker and am looking for an accurate wording:

> During the period of 09/10/2021 - 09/20/2021, our department has run an assessment test of graduate students.

I am concerned if the "during the period of ..." is used correctly as well as the "assessment test of" utilizes a right preposition. Comments on commas are also appreciated.

Comment: Most people probably wouldn't include preposition ***of*** after ***period***.

Comment: The word "during" already means "for the period that follows this word". So, ror example, instead of saying "during the period of 2020" it is more natural to just say "during 2020".

Comment: @DanielAsimov -  Except that advice doesn’t really work with a date range.

Comment: Jim: You are right — it's more awkward with a date range. I would say: "Between September 10, 2021 and September 20, 2021, ...."